# Colwise sum of matrix in a sequential order

Tags: r

I would like to do colwise sum of matrix that follow a particular sequence.  For example, if I have a matrix of 50 rows, the first four rows will be added in a colwise manner, then 2 to 5 rows, 3 to 6, ... etc. following that pattern.  How can I do this in R?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? And what should the size of the result be, 47 or 50 ? Give us an illustrated example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(sample(100,50*10,replace=TRUE),nrow=50)
n <- nrow(mat)
sapply(1:(n-3), function(i) colSums(mat[i:(i+3),]))
```

#Update

```
oddInd <- sapply(1:(n-3), function(i) {ind <-i:(i+3); ind[!!ind%%2] })
evenInd <- sapply(1:(n-3), function(i) {ind <-i:(i+3); ind[!ind%%2] })
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to separate the odd and even indices?